# Is there a country in the world not in debt?

Tags: international-economics, government-debt

This morning I read the following article:

https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-49961301

It got me thinking, is there any country in the world not in debt? I am aware that debt is good for a country, but to what extent? I am fairly uneducated in this area so please educate me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Research in this area is pretty controversial. You want to google debt to GDP ratio (and [putative] effects on growth). See https://www.theguardian.com/business/economics-blog/2013/apr/17/rogoff-reinhart-defend-debt-study for instance

Comment: Nevertheless academics still publish quite a bit about it. [This slightly more recent paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmacro.2014.03.009) has been cited a fair bit. Not sure if it's because it's controversial or just accepted.

Comment: @Fizz why is this area so controversial? Seems like a good subject to educate people on

Comment: The results are controversial for political reasons. Also establishing causality is never easy in retrospect, so the methodology is complex and prone to criticism. See also https://doi.org/10.1016/j.iref.2014.09.007 or https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpolmod.2015.09.004 (the latter in more extended form: http://www.bath.ac.uk/economics/research/working-papers/2017-papers/heterogeneity-in-the-debt-growth-nexus.pdf)

Comment: Also "debt overhang" is something you may want to look into e.g. https://www.esm.europa.eu/sites/default/files/wp36final.pdf

Answer (score 2):

According to the World Economic Outlook database (April 2018), in 2018, the "General government net debt" of these countries was negative:

> Kazakhstan, Norway, Trinidad and Tobago, Luxembourg, Botswana, Oman, Estonia.

This database doesn't have this datum for Singapore, but I believe the Singapore government also has negative net debt.